# How to optimise join between two MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: p_group.full_data, which is a large dataset I'm working on (100k rows, 200 columns) and p_group.full_data_aggregated, which I've produced to summarise a load of other tables.

Now, what I'd like to do is perform a join between full_data and full_data_aggregated to select out certain rows, averages, and so on. The query I have is as follows:

```
SELECT 'name', p.group_id, a.group_condition, p.event_index, AVG(p.value) FROM p_group.full_data p 
JOIN p_group.full_data_aggregated as a on p.group_id = a.group_id AND p.event_index = a.event_index
WHERE (a.group_condition='open') 
GROUP BY p.group_id, p.event_index
```

I have an index on: full_data.group_id, full_data.event_index and full_data_aggregated.group_id, full_data_aggregated.event_index, full_data_aggregated.group_condition.

Now, the problem is that this query simply won't finish: previously, I had my full_data split up into different tables (one for each group_id), and that worked fine. But now that I have joined the groups together, the query sits there running and so I can only assume I have done something stupid.

Is there anything else I can try to actually get this query to run at a decent speed? I'm sure I've messed up something with indices and the group by function, but I can't work out what. I've tried all sorts of variations of the above query. EXPLAIN indicates that it is "using where; using temporary; using filesort" but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm just curious... are You working on some kind of multidimensional analysis, maybe trying to crack forex?

Comment: Have you checked your database's query plan to see if it is doing any large table scans?

Comment: hah, sadly I'm analysing some boring data from an experiment. I have no idea what forex even is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your indexes are combination indexes (with group_id and event_index together).  If you have *separate* indexes for each field, then only *one* index is used at a time and the database engine is going through significantly more data.

For example, if you only have a few unique group_id, but *lots* of event_index, and you have two indexes, one on group_id only, and the other one on event_index, then you query is going to run through a large number of rows for each group_id.  If you have *one* index instead, with both fields in order, then the query will run much faster.

Comment: Perfect! I have a fair number of group_index (30 or so) and hundreds of event_index. I had of course failed to set up a combination index. Now it runs in 0.6 secs. I'll keep your points in mind for when everything gets out of control and I have to re-organise my indices again! Thanks ! :)

Comment: What database engine are you using? The database engine should notice that you have very few unique group_id's (based on index statistics) and make the query plan to use the event_index instead.  Still, it won't be as fast as a combination index.

Comment: Ah right, it's MyISAM at the moment. Is there a better choice for this kind of query?

Comment: I don't know much about MyISAM, sorry.  However, after second thoughts, it may not help (without a combo index, that is) even with an advanced database because your GROUP BY clause groups first by group_id.  If the query optimizer goes with the event_index index, then it'll have to build a temp result table in memory before doing the GROUP BY -- which may be a *very* large table.  So it is wise to go with the group_id index instead -- in that case, the whole grouping is done in a streaming manner, no need for an intermediate table.

Comment: An index always out-performs any database engine optimizations.  However, an index incurs costs when updating/inserting/deleting.  In your case, perhaps you'd like to keep the tables clear of most indexes, only building those special indexes before you try to do these maintenance operations, and drop the indexes afterwards.

Comment: Good plan - the indexes will probably need to change depending on the operation being run, so I think I will need to do something like this when it gets more complex. Thanks!